# Copying an image with PHP

Tags: php, image, curl, fopen

With permission from the other site, I am supposed to periodically download an image hosted on another site and include it in a collection of webcam photos on our site with an external link to the contributing site.

This hasn't been any issue for any of the other sites, but with this particular one, I can't open the image to resize it and save it to our server. It's not a hotlinking issue because I can create a plain ole' `<img src="http://THEIRIMAGE />` on a page on our site and it works fine.

I've tried using `$img = new Imagick($sourceFilePath)` directly as with all the others, as well as trying to use PHP's copy and also trying to copy the image using cURL but when doing so, the page just times out with no results at all.

Here's the image in question:  http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapshotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard

Like I've said, I'm able to do this sort of thing with several other webcams, but it isn't working with this one, and I am stuck as to why it isn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You clarified that you have permission from the other site to get their pictures. Good on you.

Comment: That url works fine here with file_get_contents().

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce bandwidth and server load some sites block certain bots from accessing their content. Your cURL request needs to more closely mimic an actual browser, which would include a referrer (usually), user agent, etc. It could also be that there is a redirect and you haven't told cURL to follow redirects.

Try setting more opts like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

If that doesn't work, get the user agent from an actual browser and put it in there and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've tried this with an actual USERAGENT string plugged in (pulled from FireBug) and it still just times out.

Comment: It could also be that your server's IP somehow got blacklisted from the remote server. Since it's working for Marc B in the comment above, there must be something wrong with your server accessing it. Try downloading it from the command line to see if that helps narrow things down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

for example:

```
$url = 'http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapshotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard';
$outputfile = "tmp/image" . date("Y-m-d_H.i.s");
$cmd = "wget -q \"$url\" -O $outputfile";
exec($cmd);
$temp_img = file_get_contents($outputfile);
$img = new Imagick($temp_img);
```

Can you try this and get back to me?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but file_get_contents just times out as well.

Comment: Are you on a windows or linux environment? If you are on linux try wget-ing the image from the command line. If it downloads it correctly then try something like I will update above.